# Метод разницы двух обыкновенных дробей С++

Tags: c++, ооп

Всем привет
Мне нужна помощь с моим методом
Вот код:

```
void difference(){
    int d,a,b;
    int resultnum = ((num1 * den2) - (num2 * den1));
    int resultden = (den1 * den2);
    
    a = resultnum, b = resultden;
    while(a > 0 && b > 0){
        if(a > b){
            a %= b;
        }
        else{
            b %= a; 
        }
        d = a + b;
    }
cout << num1 << "/" << den1 << " - " << num2 << "/" << den2 << " = " << resultnum / d << "/" << resultden / d;
}
```

Что он собственно делает,на вход он получает 4 числа num1,den1,num2,den2
Тоесть num1 - Числитель первой дроби, den1 - Знаменатель
resultnum - числитель дроби полученной в результате разницы двух дробей
resultden - знаменатель

Дальше мне надо сократить дроби,для этого ищу для числителя и знаменателя НОД, все работает вроде бы хорошо,но вот когда num1 == num2 и den1 == den2 цикл крашится.Тоесть когда числа разные все работает,но когда дроби одинаковые результат должен быть 0. А цикл крашиться.Может кто-то помочь как это исправить?

Comment: алгоритм НОД евклида не расчитан на нулевые значения. надо проверять числа на ноль сначала. перед циклом `while` поставить `if ( a == 0 ) d = b ;`

Comment: код мог упасть по причине неопределённого значения переменной `int d;` и когда она случайно принимает значение ноль, происходит критическая ситуация.